# What does "native" mean on a Capybara::Element object?

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

For some reason I can't access the contents of the `<title>` tag in a `Capybara::Element`, even though:

1. I can access the contents of other tags
2. The contents of the title tag is available via other means

What is special about the `Capybara::Element` for the `<title>` tag?

```
page.body[0..100]
=> "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>\n<head>\n<title>monkeyX</title>\n<meta content=\"Co"
page.title
=> "monkeyX"
page.find('title', visible: false).text
=> ""
page.find('article').text
=> "Newsfeed Post by Test User, MD Test User, MD Test User, MD Anytown, ND hello lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit proin risus Read More Share Share this Post 0 March 26, 2015 7:35pm"
```

**update**

Looks like `native` does the trick:

```
page.find('title', visible: false).native.text
=> "monkeyX"
```

What does native mean?

Answer (score 2):

`title` only returns visible text (you can pass `:all` to ask for all text).

The `native` method returns the underlying object from the driver - behaviour may vary occording to which driver you use (poltergeist, rack::test) etc.